# UIBarButtonItem action not work UITableView cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibarbuttonitem

I create UIBarbUttonItem inside UITableView cell programmatically like this :

```
func setupChildrenPicker(){
    let chooseButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: Wordings.BTN_CHOOSE, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: nil, action: #selector(self.pickerChildrenDonePressed))
}

func pickerChildrenDonePressed(){
    print ("pickerChildrenDonePressed")
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    setupChildrenPicker()
}
```

but when I click that BarButtonItem, it not called pickerChildrenDonePressed() function (did not create log pickerChildrenDonePressed).

What is the correct code to make it called pickerChildrenDonePressed?

Comment: You should share more compilable code to reproduce the issue. Is there any specific reason to use `UIBarButtonItem` instead of `UIButton`?

Comment: I don't think you should use `UIBarButtonItem` for places other than _Navigation Bar_, _Toolbars_,  _Tab Bar_ . For places other than this, use `UIButton` . Is there a specific reason you are using `UIBarButtonItem` instead of `UIButton`

Comment: because it will call pickerView when I click custom button in tableview cell. and that pickerView is custom. UIBarButtonItem are created both on left and right top side, done and cancel. Can UIButton replace that UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: Set the **target** inside `UIBarButtonItem(title: Wordings.BTN_CHOOSE, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: nil, action: #selector(self.pickerChildrenDonePressed)` to **self** instead of _nil_

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi, your answer is correct. Thanks.

Comment: As @ShubhamBakshi suggested use this:
let chooseButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: Wordings.BTN_CHOOSE, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.pickerChildrenDonePressed))

Comment: @Sarimin Ok , thanks. I have answered your question just in case someone needs a future reference to the same !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

Inside

`UIBarButtonItem(title: Wordings.BTN_CHOOSE, style:UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: nil, action: #selector(self.pickerChildrenDonePressed)`

change **target** to `self` instead of *nil*